# Rstudio is not opening

Tags: r, rstudio

It just says

> loading workspace from ~/.Rdata...

and the wheel just keeps spinning.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Rstudio. I've tried the `Interrupt R`, `Terminate R`, and `Restart R` from the Session dropdown. Any ideas?

Comment: Try opening a new RStudio session **while** the other session is still loading the .Rdata

Comment: OK, I just tried that. Both sessions have the loading message still.

Comment: Lots more info needed to begin offering suggestions ... like which version of RStudio, which version of R, and which OS are you using?

Comment: Sure. R version 3.2.2. RStudio 0.99.489. Windows 10. Also, for what it's worth, the load screen says this: Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

Comment: Try to run "Run Diagnostics.lnk" which should be in the same folder as rstudio.exe

Comment: Any idea where that file is? I've searched for it and it didn't come up.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hidden-files#show-hidden-files=windows-7  The `.RData` file should be in the working directory you use in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recall this happening to me once and I believe the solution was to remove the .Rdata file it is trying to load.  If you need it, move it then try loading from within RStudio after it finally starts.

Comment: Yes! This worked. In the working directory folder there was a workspace file that was huge (some large random forests). Deleted that and it opened just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the .Rdata file did not help for me as well, I even tried reinstalling.

The issue was fixed only after I deleted the entire folder %LocalAppData%\RStudio-Desktop

Answer (score 0):

Not intended as an answer to the specific problem of:

> loading workspace from ~/.Rdata...

but I had a similar problem with RStudio just spinning after a restart and deleting the .Rdata file did not help.

There was a tab open in the Source pane that was used for viewing XML from a URL using `url.show()`. Eventually RStudio loaded after about 10 minutes of being unresponsive, and when I closed that tab and restarted RStudio, it started as normal. I'm not sure how I would have resolved that if the XML was too big to be loaded into memory and RStudio kept trying to open it, though the 'official comment' on this RStudio Support Community question on the location of unsaved script tabs might be helpful:

> The project folder contains a hidden folder called .Rproj.user, which contains most of RStudio's state for the project. If you search in the subfolders of .Rproj.user for folders named sdb (short for "source database"), you may find some files that have the contents of the unsaved tabs in JSON format.
>
> These are internal RStudio state files and you may cause instability if they're removed or altered; we recommend a good backup system and version control for recovering data.

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203104668-rstudio-unsaved-script-tabs-loaction

It's also touched on in the comments of this SO question:

[Where does RStudio store the temporary R script files before saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965581/where-does-rstudio-store-the-temporary-r-script-files-before-saved)