# Where does RStudio store the temporary R script files before saved?

Tags: r, rstudio

I've just had RStudio crash on me unexpectedly, and on re-starting, contrary to what I've come to expect, the R script I had been tinkering around with was nowhere to be found.

I've managed to track down the Rhistory file so I'll be able to piece together all the commands, which is reassuring.

However, I *am* curious if there's somewhere I might try looking to find the temporary unsaved file on the off chance that might be cached somewhere (after all, it is *usually* cached somewhere that RStudio apparently knows to look). Is there a particular file extension/format I should be searching for?

Currently running R 3.3.1 through RStudio 0.99.903 on Linux Mint 17.3 (over Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS).

---

I've tried running `grep` on the command line to find some of the more recently updated lines of code; I may be out of luck. I found two files:

```
~/.rstudio-desktop/history_database
```

Which appears to basically be a more centralized .Rhistory for RStudio

and

```
~/.rstudio-desktop/sdb/s-9CD2C698/D7986B2A
```

This looks JSON-like and also appears to basically be an Rhistory. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: did you open up the same project (or close a project)? you might be in a different workspace when you reopen than you were in when it crashed

Comment: @rawr indeed something like that happened -- when RStudio restarted, some other scripts from a different "project" came, but it was all outside of any _project_ (meaning an official .Rproj file), since I was just tinkering on one-off web scraping run.

Comment: You are correct that RStudio stores autosave data as part of the JSON 'blobs' within the `sdb` folder. You should see the document serialized as a long 'string', with newlines embedded. It's a little bit strange / unintuitive, but that's what it is for now at least!

Comment: If you run the script line by line, then the `history_database` file should contain the last commands that you run.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As indicated by @KevinUshey from RStudio:

> RStudio stores autosave data as part of the JSON 'blobs' within the sdb folder. You should see the document serialized as a long 'string', with newlines embedded.

Use packages such as `jsonlite` to parse this and best of luck.

Comment: In fact, in the newest versions of RStudio, we now store these files within the `sources` folder (which is a sibling of the old `sdb` folder), and we extract the document contents into a separate file post-fixed with `-contents` (encoded as UTF-8). This should hopefully make this sort of document recovery a bit easier!

Comment: @KevinUshey awesome! If you have a version tag, I can add that to the answer body (or feel free to do so yourself)

Comment: Where is this located on a Mac? I just lost a lot of work.

Comment: I found my lost work! The `sources` folder is a sub-subfolder of the `.Rproj.user` folder. I choose the appropriate subfolder by date.

Answer (score 0):

if you used Rstudio on linux, the temporary R script files were stored in .rstudio/sources folder, and you can open all of the script files directly.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In Rstudio if you saved or not a script but you ran this code, you can check the history off the app, this is the "telemetric data" that Rstudio has about you.

In windows, this is the path,

> C:\Users\ANALISTA\AppData\Local\RStudio\history_database

you should use "visual studio code" or something similar to see it.