# How can I get back an overwritten R document?

Tags: r, rstudio, overwrite

I managed to overwrite an essential R script in R Studio. If I open the document now, I see the previous version from one month ago. As the versions had the same name, the new version got overwritten when I by mistake inserted the old version (from an external hard disk) in the same computer folder. I now am desperate as I wrote much stuff in the R script in the last few week - all gone. Can anyone help me? I know there are options to get back pervious versions of files in Microsoft office like Word but is there a similar function in R?

I already talked to an IT expert but unfortunately he doen't have any experience with R or R Studio.

Comment: Nothing in R or RStudio allows you to recover your code. Only regular backups or Git commits can help you with that, but you need to have them set up *in the past*. If you didn't, there is nothing that can be done.

Comment: Unlikely this will help, but can't hurt to mention it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965581/where-does-rstudio-store-the-temporary-r-script-files-before-saved